# Merge [esoteric] and [esoteric-languages] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[esoteric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric) and [esoteric-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric-languages) are the same thing, request to merge them.

Comment: @Deduplicator The tag was obviously not correct for that question (saying that a bug/error is "esoteric" just because you can't figure out what is causing it is nonsense) so I removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [esoteric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric) tag is cleared now.

Questions about esoteric languages are re-tagged with [esoteric-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric-languages).

And it's removed from other questions (only several) not related to esoteric languages