# Can we process the tag synonym requests?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

It’s a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/180500) that the current tag synonym process doesn’t seem to be working effectively.

In the meantime, we have several [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) on meta.  Unfortunately, posting to meta doesn’t seem to be working effectively either.  Even for [the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253336/tag-synonym-request-volley-and-android-volley) [simple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250200/merge-esoteric-and-esoteric-languages-tags) [ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251115/make-these-specific-jquery-and-jquery-ui-tags-synonyms).

Issues that affect as many posts as a tag do would seem to merit a bit more time and attention than this.  Is the problem that users active on meta are also not privileged enough to act on this?  Moderators, is there a reason we can’t get these posts to either a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (other than the limits on your time, of course)?  Maybe we can even get the system fixed so that the community can handle this on its own.

Comment: I find that quite a few tag requests are completed without ever being marked as [tag:status-completed]. If you see one of these, please raise a custom flag so it can be tagged appropriately.